# Blur Surrounding Of Expanded RecyclerView Item (Blur RecyclerView Except Of One Of Its Items)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` containing its children:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, each item can be expanded (for example item i in the picture).
In my project I use [this blur library](https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView) to blur things, for example, clicking the `FloatingActionButton` expands it to a dialog, and the dialog's surrounding is blurred, like this:

[image]

I want that an expanded `RecyclerView`s item will have its surrounding blurred as well. I tried this:

(`Item.xml`:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
        android:id="@+id/blur_view_per_active_goal_card"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:realtimeBlurRadius="20dp"
        app:realtimeOverlayColor="#8000"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/root_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/active_goal_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <com.example.performancemeasurement.customViews.CustomProgressBar.CustomProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/active_goal_item_progress_bar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:transitionName="progressBar"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:enable_gradient="true" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/active_goal_item_open_close_image_button"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/down_vector" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:visibility="gone">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Goal Name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <com.example.performancemeasurement.customViews.CustomProgressBar.CustomProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_progress_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/expanded_active_goal_card_label"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:transitionName="progressBar"
                    app:enable_gradient="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/expanded_active_goal_card_progress_bar"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:text="Goal's Description"
                    android:textColor="#6F6F6F"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_label_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/expanded_active_goal_card_description"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="14">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goal_label_left"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_label"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="SubGoals"
                        android:textColor="#5A5A5A"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goal_label_right"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_label_container"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:elevation="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

(putting the blurred view behind the item's content, and then in the `RecyclerView`s `ViewHolder` handle the blur visibility as I did in the Dialog example every time the item is expanded/shrunk, but even when I make it visible without handling it, the blur won't show. I tried to handle it programmatically as planned, but still, the blur didn't show up.

So the question is: Specifically in my case - where is the problem? Why won't the blur show? 
And in general... how can I blur the surrounding of a `RecyclerView`s expanded/focused item (using the `RealtimeBlurView` library or any other that suits the solution for this problem), or in other words, how can I blur the whole `Recyclerview` except of one of its items / how can I blur the background of specific `View`(blur everything except this `View`.

Help would be highly appreciated! (:

Answer (score 1):

You must put `RealtimeBlurView` above another view to make that view blur but in your implementation, `RealtimeBlurView` is below `CardView`, so you can't see the Bure effect. You must put it after `CardView` in your layout file. Try the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/root_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/active_goal_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <com.example.performancemeasurement.customViews.CustomProgressBar.CustomProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/active_goal_item_progress_bar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:transitionName="progressBar"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:enable_gradient="true" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/active_goal_item_open_close_image_button"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/down_vector" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:visibility="gone">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Goal Name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <com.example.performancemeasurement.customViews.CustomProgressBar.CustomProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_progress_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/expanded_active_goal_card_label"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:transitionName="progressBar"
                    app:enable_gradient="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/expanded_active_goal_card_progress_bar"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:text="Goal's Description"
                    android:textColor="#6F6F6F"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_label_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/expanded_active_goal_card_description"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="14">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goal_label_left"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_label"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="SubGoals"
                        android:textColor="#5A5A5A"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goal_label_right"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_label_container"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:elevation="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_active_goal_card_sub_goals_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
        android:id="@+id/blur_view_per_active_goal_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/cardView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cardView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cardView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/cardView"
        app:realtimeBlurRadius="20dp"
        app:realtimeOverlayColor="#8000"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**
Since you need to blur other items except for expanded item, you should handle it in your adapter implementation. The following code snippet shows how to implement it.
**MyAdapter.kt**

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener {

    val items = ArrayList<Item>()
    var expandedItemIndex = -1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view, this)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        items.get(position)?.apply { holder.bind(this, expandedItemIndex) }
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        v?.let {
            if(it.id == R.id.blur) {
                expandedItemIndex = -1
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else if(it.id == R.id.expand_btn) {
                val holder = it.getTag() as MyViewHolder
                if (expandedItemIndex == holder.adapterPosition) {
                    expandedItemIndex = -1;
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                } else {
                    expandedItemIndex = holder.adapterPosition
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View, onClickListener: View.OnClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val textView : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)
        val expandButton : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand_btn)
        val expandArea : View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_area);
        val blur : View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blur);

        init {
            expandButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
            blur.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
        }

        fun bind(item: Item, expandedItemIndex: Int) {
            textView.text = item.value.toString()
            expandButton.setTag(this)
            if(expandedItemIndex >= 0) {
                blur.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                if(expandedItemIndex == adapterPosition) {
                    blur.z = -1f
                    expandArea.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    expandButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
                } else {
                    blur.z = 0f
                    expandArea.visibility = View.GONE
                    expandButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float)
                }
            } else {
                expandArea.visibility = View.GONE
                blur.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**layout_row.xml**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Header Text" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_area"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Expanded Line 1"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Expanded Line 2"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
        android:id="@+id/blur"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cardHolder"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cardHolder"
        app:realtimeBlurRadius="20dp"
        app:realtimeOverlayColor="#8000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyAdapterJava.Java** (Java implementaion of adapter)

```
public class MyAdapterJava extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterJava.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    int expandedItemIndex = -1;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapterJava.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view, this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapterJava.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position), expandedItemIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v != null) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.blur) {
                expandedItemIndex = -1;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if(v.getId() == R.id.expand_btn) {
                MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) v.getTag();
                if (expandedItemIndex == holder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                    expandedItemIndex = -1;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    expandedItemIndex = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;
        ImageView expandButton;
        View expandArea;
        View blur;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            expandButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand_btn);
            expandArea = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_area);
            blur = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blur);

            expandButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            blur.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        }

        public void bind(Item item, int expandedItemIndex) {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(item.getValue()));
            expandButton.setTag(this);
            if(expandedItemIndex >= 0) {
                blur.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(expandedItemIndex == getAdapterPosition()) {
                    blur.setZ(-1f);
                    expandArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    expandButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
                } else {
                    blur.setZ(0f);
                    expandArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    expandButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float);
                }
            } else {
                expandArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                blur.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be like this:
[image]

**PS:**

1. Since this code is using [View.SetZ(float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setZ(float)) to handle Blur view Z position, it works on API 21 and above. For supporting lower API versions, you should add another Blur view before `FrameLayout (cardHolder)` view in layout file and instead of using `View.setZ(float)` method, make proper Blur view visible.

2. When an item is expanded and other items are blurred, scrolling of RecyclerView still works but it doesn't affect on the functionality of my answer. If you need to disable it, you should define a callback in your Adapter and call it in `override fun onClick(v: View?)` method to notify activity or fragment to disable/enable RecyclerView scrolling.

Comment: But I want the background of the card to be blurred, not the card itself... Putting the blurView after a View puts it in front of it, not behind it...

Comment: I thought putting it before the very item template of the RecyclerView might put it behind it but in front of all the RecyclerView, but as you can see it's not working

Comment: Do you want to blur the white area of your card? Could you please share a picture and show the area that you like to make it blur?

Comment: I'd like to have everything but the expanded card blurred, as if the card was the dialog in the second picture (it's not the card, but in the second picture everything except the dialog is blurred. As the dialogs background is blurred, I want the expanded-cards background to be blurred)... What other pictures should I add?

Comment: Do you like the final result like [this image](https://i.ibb.co/F4PmCTQ/blur.jpg)?

Comment: yes!!! exactly! (and I want the blur to be a bit darker, and clickable, so clicking on it will shrink the card back and the blur will fade out)

Comment: Look at my updated answer, I hope it will be useful.

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot for helping! second, I don't know Kotlin yet, and converting it to Java using Android Studios tools doesn't make it readable for me either... can you please write the code in Java? and if you can please just update my adapter class that I shared the code of in the question... Anyway, you'll get the bounty because it seems like you've solved the problem and due to the lack of time 'till it ends, but I'll not give you the 'solved' mark yet... I really hope you'll help me understand the answer (: thanks a lot!

Comment: I added the java implementation of my adapter. You can easily modify the `layout_row.xml` and `MyAdapterJava.java` to implement your desired UI.

Comment: I finally had some time to try this, and I understood that this method cancels the animations... I want the card expansion to be animated... also I understood that it blurs each card separately... it can't be efficient, is it? can you please help me find a better-suited solution? (:

Comment: You can add animation by yourself, or use one of the expandable adapter libraries. Yes it blurs each card separately but the final result is like what you need.

Comment: it is what I need, but in case I'll have a lot of items on the list, won't it make the app crash or something?

Comment: I did test with 100 simple items and I didn't face any problem.

Comment: I won't give 'solve' mark to the answer, because it still doesn't work as I wanted it to... thank you for trying to help anyway! (:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the blurry library https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry. Its the easiest way of making a blurred background.

With this library, you only had to use below piece of snippet

```
Blurry.with(context).radius(10).sampling(8).color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0)).async().onto(rootView);
```

Hope this will fit perfect according to your requirement!!

Comment: I saw this, but wasn't sure how to apply this on my rectclerview... Where should I use it, in the ViewHolder? And what's the rootView in this case?

Comment: Plus, I didn't mention it but I want the card to shrink when clicking the blurred background, and I can't see how it works with this solution (If it actually solves the problem)

Comment: @Deeksha this library does not work with androidX (renderscript has some serious issues on AndroidX, so pretty much no blurry library - and I tried at least 5-6 of them - works with projects using android X).